# Why can't I start mysql service on ec2 linux instance

Tags: linux, mysql, ssh, amazon-ec2

I get this error when starting mysql via ssh on  my ec2 ami linux instance:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/libysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Before running "mysql" command i tried to start mysql service:

```
sudo service mysqld start
```

but fails.

I checked for mysql.sock in the specified directory but it was missing.  What is going on?

**EDIT**
Also i changed permissions to these directories:

```
/var/lib/mysql/ => 755
all sub-directories in /var/lib/mysql => 700
all files in /var/lib/mysql => 660
```

**EDIT**
I just uninstalled and re-installed mysql on my redhat ami ec2 instance.  And I still can't start mysql service.

**EDIT**

Here is my mysql log:

```
    170506 04:31:30 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
    2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
    ^G/usr/libexec/mysql56/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13 - Permission denied)
    2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
    2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
    2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
    2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
    2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
    2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
    2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
    2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
    ^G/usr/libexec/mysql56/mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/var/tmp/ibdSw66G' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
    2017-05-06 04:31:30 7faa567fd840  InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
    2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
    2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
    2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
    2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [ERROR] Aborting
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Binlog end
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2017-05-06 04:31:30 6516 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysql56/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

**EDIT**

I also fully uinstalled and re-installed mysql with this command couple of times now:

```
sudo yum -y remove mysql-server
sudo yum -y install mysql-server
```

**EDIT**

Alright, forget it...lol.  I just started a new amz ec2 linux instance.  THanks!

Comment: what's the error message after start? what's in `netstat -plnt | grep 3306` ?

Comment: when i type above command without sudo i get: (No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=500 but you should be root.).  And when i type with sudo, i get nothing, just goes to next commandline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13 - Permission denied)
>
> Can't create/write to file '/var/tmp/ibdSw66G ... Permission denied'

Try
`chown mysql.mysql /var/lib/mysql/ -R; chmod 1777 /var/tmp` 
Also, have you read/tried this:

> Can't open the mysql.plugin table. **Please run mysql_upgrade to create**
> it.

Comment: The correct permissions for /var/tmp should be `1777`.

Comment: I can't run mysql_upgrade without starting mysqld and running mysql.

Comment: I couldn't change permissions/owners of either directories because of "permission denied" error(s).

Comment: @Dave2345 so does it work now?

Comment: no, i just trashed this instance and started another one lol.  thanks tho.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

`mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -p <database>`

Also (to see if it's running):

`telnet 127.0.0.1 3306`

Probably it is just a misconfiguration in the my.cnf file, in /etc/ (depending on the Linux distribution).

Comment: nope still same issue.  and telnet is not found a recognized command on my server.

Comment: you can install telnet and have you checked mysql config it is configured by 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: tried that, still doesn't work.

Comment: @Dave2345 Have you opened inbound traffic for Port 3306?

Comment: Yes, in AWS console I set it.